# Using "then" in sentence which is in response to context

Tags: grammar

For example:

> Should the free market then only capture that which is beyond necessity?

I'm not sure if "then" is accomplishing anything, or if it is even correct in this sentence. Perhaps it should be written more like

> Should the free market only capture that which is beyond necessity?

But this sentence doesn't sound like it is referencing any contextual information. Perhaps this

> Then should the free market only capture that which is beyond necessity?

Comment: What are the sentences preceding this one? We need more context.

Comment: The sentences doesn't really matter, the point is that "then" is used in reference to previous statements. I'm not sure if it is okay to use it in this manner.

Comment: Yes, the preceding sentences and context matter.

Comment: 'Should the free market then only capture ...' means 'In the light of what has just been said, should the free market only capture ...'. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/then), sense ‘in that case’ ['this being the case'].